# Prevent Redux from rerendering entire tree and clearing local state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

For my app's signup form, I am maintaining the form values with local component state, but the currentUser state, error state, and the API calls are in Redux.

What I'd like to happen is when the form is submitted, the button has a loading spinner and the form values remain until a response is returned from the server. If the server responds with an authorized user, redirect to app. If there's an error, the form's values should **not** be cleared.

The problem seems to be that Redux is clearing my form values when it dispatches any state updating function (whether removing an error or making the API call to authorize the user). Is there any way to avoid this happening?

From my AuthForm.js

```
const submitData = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (formType === 'reset') {
      updatePassword(resetToken, values.password, history)
        .then(result => setLoading(false));
    } else if (formType === 'forgot') {
      forgotPassword(values.email, history);
    } else {
      console.log(values); // form values still populated
      onAuth(formType, values, history)
        .then(result => {
          console.log('result received'); // values empty
          setLoading(false);
            if (formType === 'signup') {
              history.push('/questionnaire')
            } else {
              history.push('/app')
            }
        })
        .catch(err => setLoading(false));
    }
  };
```

From my redux actions.js file:

```
export function authUser(type, userData, history) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(removeError());
    console.log('dispatch') // by this time the form values are empty
    // unless I comment out the dispatch(removeError()) above, 
    // in which case we still have values until 'token recevied' below
    return apiCall('post', `/users/${type}`, userData)
      .then(({ jwt, refresh_token, ...user }) => {
        console.log('token received')
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', jwt);
        localStorage.setItem('jwtTokenRefresh', refresh_token);
        dispatch(getUser(user.id));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        handleError(dispatch, err);
      });
  };
}
```

I'm also logging the values in my AuthForm component. The result is this:
[image]

EDIT: It definitely looks like my components are unmounting but it's still not clear why to me, or how to prevent it.
[image]

I am trying to memoize the dispatch function but it seems to have no effect.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onAuth = useCallback(
    (formType, values, history) => {
      dispatch(authUser(formType, values, history))
    },
    [dispatch]
  );
```

Comment: Your form values are in local state so I think the component is unmounted when you dispatch certain actions. Also you should prevent default if the event handler is on submit of the form.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this though? It seems like a fairly common use case, where you want to preserve local state but update something in Redux.

Comment: I also do have e.preventDefalut() in my handleSubmit() function

Comment: Avoid what? If the state reset is caused by the component remounting then you can lift the state, put it in redux or use context for that state.

Comment: Avoid the component remounting -- there is no reason for it to do so. The state is at the appropriate level since it refers to the form that is AuthForm.js' job

Comment: If your component unmounts you have to look at the parent that has the local form state and see why it unmounts. None of that code is in your question so I won't know. I assume you confirmed the component is remounted and that is was causes the sate to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is a subscriber to a redux store, thats why it re-renders,
component's state gets initialized to initial states,
Now you need, a way to persist these component states within rendering cycles.
On class component you would tie a value to a instance i.e using `this.value == 'value'`
so that it remains the same between renders,

On functional component to achieve this you  make use of a hook called `useRef`
which doesnt change its value on re-render unless you manually change it,
Hopely it will help

Comment: To add on it, use memo() from react which prevent component from re-render if its data havent change